# Clean URL with htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I am new on this forum, so i need help. I'm working on my website with PHP/MySQL and I stack with .htaccess

So there is my code

```
<a href="namebook-'.$row['book_name'].'" class="btnmore">Review</a>
```

And there is my htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^book/namebook-([a-zA-Z0-9.\/\-\?\&]+)\.php$ book/namebook.php?name=$1
```

And with code I get URL like this:
mywebsite.com/book/namebook-book1

So I want to get clean URL like this: mywebsite/book/book1

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to remove `namebook` from the first part of the URL?

i.e. change this:

```
<a href="namebook-'.$row['book_name'].'" class="btnmore">Review</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="'.$row['book_name'].'" class="btnmore">Review</a>
```

Comment: i remove it ,but then my php dosen't recognizes 'book_name' from db, also i delete it from htaccess.
I have trable with
RewriteRule ^book/([a-zA-Z0-9.\/\-\?\&]+)\.php$ book/namebook.php?name=$1

when i replace it with some other text it's work, but when i delete it it's not work then

Answer (score 0):

The key here is your last rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^book/namebook-([a-zA-Z0-9.\/\-\?\&]+)\.php$ book/namebook.php?name=$1
```

Your rewrite rule is sending your requested value (anything that matches `[a-zA-Z0-9.\/\-\?\&]+`) to your PHP script but only if your URL matches `book/namebook-<variable>` - e.g. `mywebsite/book/namebook-book1`.

To allow `mywebsite/book/book1` you need to remove `namebook-` from the start of your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^book/([a-zA-Z0-9.\/\-\?\&]+)\.php$ book/namebook.php?name=$1
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Comment: Sorry Scott, I'm on my phone and will update tomorrow with explanation. Sorry!